# The "security" tag is ambiguous. Should we re-define it according to the general meaning?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just noticed the [security](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) tag has an ambiguous meaning.  I started to address this with some tag edits, and then realized I should post here about it so we can discuss & document the decision, since I'm also proposing to change the current tag wiki definition.

Here's the problem:

- On the one hand, the tag wiki currently defines "security" in the sense of **finance**: *"A security (also known as a financial instrument) is a tradable asset of any kind. For questions related to a specific asset class, use a specific tag, e.g. "stock" or "bond"."*  There are/were a handful of questions that used the tag in this sense.
- On the other hand, **most** of the questions that actually use the [security](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) tag relate to the more **general** meaning, i.e. of being free from danger/threat or guarding against such. Questions using it in this sense talk about security tokens, online security, login credentials, identity theft, whether you can trust a company, etc.

I was thinking we would prefer that latter more general definition, since:

1. It is the prevalent use here already, and
2. I can't see the finance-specific term "security" being of significant use around here since we've already got very specific tags for the kinds of securities individuals deal with: [stocks](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stocks), [bonds](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bonds), [options](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/options), [mutual-funds](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mutual-funds), [certificate-of-deposit](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/certificate-of-deposit), etc.

So:

Should the [security](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) tag be re-defined to mean only the concept of security as in being free from danger/threat or guarding against such, e.g. as in "computer security".    I propose **yes**.  Discuss :)

Comment: Yes.<!---Filler-->

Comment: Yup. <!--All Killer-->

Comment: @MrChrister Uh oh, did I miss a memo about a moderator-only party?

Comment: @JohnBensin - uh oh.  I think you out-referenced me.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with your proposed redefinition. I'm in favor of the more general definition because

1. I think the term "security" will come up in more searches for topics related to the general definition. We already have tags addressing topics that relate to "all financial securities", e.g. [investing](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/investing) and [trading](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trading).
2. This is a minor point, but the term "security" can be somewhat ambiguous, e.g. in [these](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/21068/7590) [questions](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/11010/7590). As I said above, the general tags that cover topics that concern securities are more than adequate, in my opinion.
3. It's a purely normative preference, but tags that apply to multiple, mostly orthogonal concepts, e.g. "stocks" and "password security" should probably be split into more specific tags if possible.