# Create tag synonym: "security" and "securities"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

[security](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) and [securities](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/securities) are essentially the same. Can someone make [security](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) a synonym of [securities](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/securities)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[security](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) and [securities](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/securities) are not the same thing.

They might appear to be the same thing....

> [security](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security)  A security (also known as a financial instrument) is a
> tradable asset of any kind. For questions related to a specific asset
> class, use a specific tag, e.g. "stock" or "bond".

and

The [securities](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/securities) tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

but some questions are not following that definition of the security tag:

[Is using a firewall debit card (curve) a good solution to protect my main credit card?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/126347/is-using-a-firewall-debit-card-curve-a-good-solution-to-protect-my-main-credit)

[Is it possible to steal money from an account/card by knowing only the card number and PIN?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/125865/is-it-possible-to-steal-money-from-an-account-card-by-knowing-only-the-card-numb)

[Which US banks support 3DS?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/120952/which-us-banks-support-3ds)

[Skimmers and bank accounts and banking security](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/120294/skimmers-and-bank-accounts-and-banking-security)

[How can I be sure if my grandfather's money is safe?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/115958/how-can-i-be-sure-if-my-grandfathers-money-is-safe)

and those are just from the 10 most recent questions.

The issue is how to make sure the questions about protecting money are appropriately tagged.

Comment: This actually turns out to have been discussed several years ago: https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/817/the-security-tag-is-ambiguous-should-we-re-define-it-according-to-the-general - but what's missing is a proposed tag for the concept of a financial instrument. Maybe we can come up with one now

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest moving the description of `security` to the `securities` keyword, as that's exactly what "securities" means, and any other definition would be confusing.

Then add a description to the `security` tag, stating that it is for ways of protecting one's assets, whether physically (e.g. bank safe deposit boxes) or financially (e.g. relatively safe, low-risk investments).

(Tags would have to be adjusted on existing questions of course.)

Comment: I started the process of editing the 'securities' tag. Please view it and edit furthur if you wish. I'll revisit the question for each tag to confirm they are being applied correctly.